# Run samsung Smart tv project to emulator crashes

Tags: javascript

My samsung tv apllication for seeing video of local channels is crashing when i am seeing this on Emulator 2012.
sometime getting black screen and no response from the remote. The app is crashing. 
 My infolink version is:- **T-INFOLINK2012-1000**

Video I am getting from xml parsing. why video is delaying to start on and crashing sometimes later????

Answer (score 0):

If you start the emulator through Eclipse it uses a lot of memory. Try the standalone version, it should not go in memory overflow.